# MUST + perfect infinitive (obligation)

Tags: modal-verbs

As far as I know people say that "must have done" can't express obligation in the past. However, how would you classify these sentences then?

> 1 To qualify for this position, you must have had a two-year working
> experience in the position of sales-manager.
>
> 2 To qualify for this position, you must not have been married.

What is this if it's not an obligation in the past?

Comment: It is not in the past tense, both of them are present perfect.

Comment: I didn't say "past tense", I said "obligation in the past". And no, there is no present perfect here either.

Comment: The sentences are not expressing an obligation. They are expressing a condition - a requirement that applicants for the job must meet. You could reword them as: **This position requires two years of working experience as sales manager** and **This position requires someone who has not been married**